# Exceeded maximum limit of 5 connections. Connection refused

Tags: db2, cloud, ibm-cloud, dashdb

I want to drop a table in IBM Db2 on cloud but I receive this error:

> Exceeded maximum limit of 5 connections. Connection refused

What should I have to do?

Comment: Wait until someone else has disconnected. Or ask the dba to add more connections.

Comment: Disconnect one of them